# Powershell to get private IP of specific VM

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-4.0, azure-automation

I am trying to get private IP of specific VM's. I have this code which is working

```
$vms = get-azurermvm -ResourceGroupName abc

$nics = get-azurermnetworkinterface -ResourceGroupName abc| where VirtualMachine -NE $null #skip Nics with no VM

foreach($nic in $nics)
{
    $vm = $vms | where-object -Property Id -EQ $nic.VirtualMachine.id
    $prv =  $nic.IpConfigurations | select-object -ExpandProperty PrivateIpAddress
    Write-Output "$($vm.Name) : $prv"
}
```

I have VM with name `es-client-node1`, `es-client-node2`, `es-master-node1`, `es-data-node1` & `es-data-node1`. I want to get IP address of just client node or VM's name matches with `es-client-node*`, similarly for datanode & master node into different variable

any idea how to do this in powershell ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For getting private IP using PowerShell you can use this command:

```
$IP = (Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $VMName -ResourceGroupName $RGName).IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress
```

Comment: doing this with powershell core threw the following error


`Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface: The 'Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface' command was found in the module 'AzureRM.Network', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module AzureRM.Network'.`


In case anyone else runs into the same issue changing `Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface` to `Get-AzNetworkInterface` solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

```
az network nic list --query '[*].{Name:name,PrivateIpAddress:ipConfigurations[0].privateIpAddress,ResourceGroup:resourceGroup}'
```